# What is the inverse Laplace transform of $\sin\left[\sqrt{\frac{r-s}{D}}x\right]$, from $s$ to $t$

Tags: inverse-laplace

I was doing a exercise and I couldn't finish it because I needed to do this inverse Laplace transform, and I got no idea how to do it. I tried convolution, I expanded the sin to complex exponential and got nothing in the end. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What does "Laplace transform ... from $s$ to $t$" mean?

Comment: When you do the inverse you get a f(t).

Comment: And what are $r,D,x$?

Comment: You can consider them as constants, only s is the variable.

Comment: Is there any reason to have both $x$ and $D$ as constants?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your time, but I don't need an answer anymore. I changed my approach on the exercise and I didn't use this inverse laplace.